# They said it would be easy: "Simple" website/app for work

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, touch, touchdevelop

I was trying not to do this, but I’m stumped and I could use help.
Work asked me to make an iPad interactive for the library.

Essentially it’s five screens- one home screen with four touch options and four sub pages with media (video and photos) and a back button to return you to the home screen.
It needs to run on two iPads connected to wifi.

The trouble I’ve had with writing this is the touch element- it’s like they’re asking me for something that is more than a website but less than an app, and I don’t know how to code that.
I worked up something with four buttons on TouchDevelop, but it looks janky and I can’t add the eternal media. I’ve been reading about HTML5 and Javascript, but I seem to be going in circles.
I’m stumped! It seems so simple and I’m getting nowhere. I've searched on stackoverflow using tags like iPad, touch, and media, but the responses are for specific bugs; I need help with the workflow.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated- this is my first non-spreadsheet assignment at work.

Comment: Managers always say it's easy, then they can not-pay you for the overtime it took you to figure it out.

Comment: Any reason you can't setup a simple Wordpress site, setup the 5 pages, and access it via iPad's web browser?

Comment: This actually sounds like a decent assignment to get started with web development, provided it is acceptable to load the application as a website. I am not all too sure that TouchDevelop will make it any easier. Not familiar with it, but seems heavyweight for your purposes. @Matt 's suggestion might help you as well (Wordpress). Have a look at some more lightweight libraries like jQuery Mobile to get started with touch events. On an added note: try to break down your question into smaller questions and build some simple functional prototypes to answer these. Ask help with the smaller q's here.